# Show Activity and after load its elements

Tags: android, android-activity, load

There's any way to call a activity and when it's appear to the user, load the elements in it? Something like facebook, when you go to any screen, it's appear and after load the contents (example below). Everytime I call my activity, it takes 2 seconds to appear.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your main views visibility `gone` and replace that with some default views and then use `asynctask` and load your data in `doInBackground()` method. then make your main views `visible` again and default views `gone` in `onPostExecute()` method

also you can simply change your views background before and after data loading in `asynctask`

Comment: That's it. But I can only interact with my views inside of onPostExecute method. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can make your content view hidden till data is loaded then set visibility with visible , add loading layout visible till data is loaded then make it gone when your data load